# Sendgrid - The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, smtp, sendgrid

I just signed up with sendgrid to send emails from my asp.net/vb.net application. I AM NOT using the API. I don't want to use the API. I just want to use the existing DotNetOpenMail library I've always used and connect to sendgrid to send emails.

```
Dim newmail1 As New EmailMessage
adding body, from, to, bla bla bla
Dim newserver2 As New SmtpServer("smtp.sendgrid.net", 587)
Dim at2 As SmtpAuthToken = New SmtpAuthToken("apikey", "SG.XXXXXXXXXX")
newserver2.SmtpAuthToken = at2
newmail1.Send(newserver2)
```

Obviously the XXXXX is the API KEY that I generated. I get this error

***Authentication failed: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked.***

When I config my sender authentication I gave FULL ACCESS. I don't know why this is an issue.

My app is using SSL. I thought maybe I'd switch the port to 465 and re-try but when I do it just hangs. I debug and it hangs on the .Send line and literally just sits there processing. I let it go and came back 24 hours ago and the browser was still chugging away. I'm using TLS 1.2 in my app so I'd prefer to use port 587.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out DotNetOpenMail isn't that great with SendGrid. Everything was fine, but I switched to System.Net.Mail and everything worked. Maybe it was the fact that System.Net.Mail uses the networkcredentials object and dotnotopenmail uses the authtoken?

Answer (score 0):

It worked this way for me:

```
Dim objat2 As New DotNetOpenMail.SmtpAuth.SmtpAuthToken("user", "pass")
```